# Using ORM Vs. SP when developing a Solely Reporting Oriented Application

Tags: stored-procedures, orm, reporting, rdlc

I have a requirement to design a Web Application which acts as a Facade for Reports based on a specific Schema, However, i have been given the whole choice to design and develop the Application in any Methodology and Technology, regardless of the argument, i have chosen to use RDLC (Client) for reports.

My Question is, in this case, is it better to use a Classic ADO.NET as my Data Access Layer (DataSets, DataTables,etc..) with Stored Procedures, or it is better to use ORM (lets say, NHibernate is the Choice) with ObjectDataSource in the UI ?

The major argument is that I'm expecting a very major changes in Reports and/or Schema it self.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own Question, i ended up using a Mixed Solution (ORM + Hard Coded SPs), i have used LinqToSql (as my ORM) while developing and utilizing Stored Procedures.

The major reason of this mix is to follow Client's Standards in Solution Development , which is based on SPs, also, the LinqToSql came as just a helper to call Stored Procedures (Also, forced to use it this way).